# Mysql - Divide 1 query for another one in the same table

Tags: mysql

A table with currency, rates, temptime - I want to divide some selected rates for the USD rate in the same temptime .             .

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `currency_rates` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 , `currency` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL
 , `rate` FLOAT NOT NULL
 , `temptime` DATE NOT NULL
 , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;


INSERT INTO `currency_rates` 
(currency, rate, temptime)
VALUES 
('USD', '1.232', '2018-03-16'),
('AUD', '133.82', '2018-03-16'),
('CAD', '1.99', '2018-03-16'),
('EUR', '1.6654', '2018-03-16'),
('USD', '1.242', '2018-03-17'),
('AUD', '132.82', '2018-03-17'),
('CAD', '1.79', '2018-03-17'),
('EUR', '1.4654', '2018-03-17'),
('USD', '1.272', '2018-03-19'),
('AUD', '123.82', '2018-03-19'),
('CAD', '1.765', '2018-03-19'),
('EUR', '1.254', '2018-03-19');


$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT currency, rate, temptime  FROM `currency_rates` WHERE currency = 'USD' ORDER BY temptime asc"); 

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT currency, date, rate FROM `currency_rates` WHERE currency IN ('AUD', 'CAD', 'EUR') ORDER BY temptime asc"); 

$result3 = I want that every rate from $result2 is divided for the USD rate from $result1 with the same temptime.
```

Thanks

Comment: What are the expected results based on the example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a cross join the USD query

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT a.currency, a.date, a.rate/b.rate
          FROM `currency_rates` a 
          CROSS JOIN  `currency_rates` b 
          WHERE b.currency = 'USD'
          AND  a.currency IN ('AUD', 'CAD', 'EUR') 
          ORDER BY a.temptime asc");
```

and if you need  the result for each temptime (as suggested  by RaymondNijland)

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT a.currency, a.date, a.rate/b.rate
          FROM `currency_rates` a 
          INNER JOIN  `currency_rates` b  ON  a.temptime = b.temptime
          AND b.currency = 'USD'
          AND a.currency IN ('AUD', 'CAD', 'EUR') 
          ORDER BY a.temptime asc");
```

Comment: "I want that every rate from $result2 is divided for the USD rate from $result1 with the same temptime. " i think the query should include `AND a.temptime = b.temptime` in the WHERE clause also.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  could be ..answer  updated  with your suggestion  too ..  many thanks   ..

Comment: Thanks, 
the second one in phpmyadmin gives me this error: 

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.temptime = b.temptime
AND b.currency = 'USD'
AND a.currency IN ('AUD', 'CAD'' at line 3`

Comment: @JuliusBarra   answer  updated .. wrong table alias  position

Comment: Thanks, now it works but it gives only the 3 rates for the EUR and not for the AUD and CAD. - I works fine if I get rid of `AND a.currency IN ('AUD', 'CAD', 'EUR') ` but  so I can't choose the currencies

Comment: My fault, I tried on a wrong table, it works fine.
Thank you very much scaisEdge and Raymond Nijland